# Difference between two files

Tags: shell

I have two files. I want to compare the files but the order of the rows is not same in both files.
Can you please provide the simplest method to compare the both files.

Example:

file1

```
My name is sumit.
My surname is vedi.
I like shell scripting.
```

file2

```
My surname is vedi.
My name is sumit.
I like shell scripting.
```

The difference between the files should be zero; however, the order of the rows is not same.
Note: the files are huge.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the command below would do the thing.

```
diff <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

If the files are huge and you do not need a sort command, then may be you could use `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file1 file2
```

The above command will only give the lines that are present in file2 but not in file1.

Comment: @sumitvedi: There is no significance to the number of fields.  If you can't sort the files, you are snookered.  This is `bash` (4.x) `process substitution'; it is about as good as it gets.  If this won't work, then you are very rapidly going to run out of options.  (How many terabytes huge are your huge files?)

Comment: The `awk` command must be able to hold all of one file in memory; the `diff` command does not need to hold very much in memory at one time.

Comment: Suppose if any line is not present in file then it gives the error for all line that's why we can't sort the file.
Eg